# visual odometry on kitty dataset using matlab

Tags: camera, computer-vision, stereo-3d

I am doing a project on visual odometery using kitty dataset.I am using matlab for my project .The following process have been used by me
 i)I am finding feature points between the 2 consecutive images and match them .
ii) I am able to get 3d points cloud using stereo configuration.
iii) I am able to compute the transformation[R|T}] between the points cloud using LMS .
iV)Use ransac to filter to get best transformation
but the result seem to be inferior specially where the car tuns and secondly few bad frame in between are ruining my whole result .I am completely stuck .

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can't really answer this without details on the algorithm an code. YOu could have various parts:
1- rotation representation error
2- concatenation of transformation error
3- ransac bug
4- using wrong calibration
5- LMS bug
6- stereo triangulation error
you will also need to do nonlinear refinement
So, to resolve the issue we need more details